# CLRegionState is UnKnown When i"m in the region

Tags: ios, core-location, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm testing iBeacon, I've used `didDetermineState:` method and the `CLRegionState` is `CLRegionStateUnknown` when I'm inside the region, can anybody tell me why?

My Bluetooth is On and detecting the beacons when I range them for CLBeaconStateUnknown, sender and receiver are in range (1 Meter), here is my Implementation

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

    switch (state) {
    case CLRegionStateInside:
        currentBeconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:currentBeconRegion];
        NSLog(@"INSIDE the Region");//not logging
        break;
    case CLRegionStateOutside:
        NSLog(@"OUTSIDE the Region");
        break;
    case CLRegionStateUnknown:
    default:
        NSLog(@"Region state UNKNOWN!!!"); //Logging on console
        statusLabel.text = @"Region state UNKNOWN!!!";
    //[self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];           
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];//Suceessfully ranging the beacon

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jhondoe: Have you overcome this issue am getting same problem when i was working on jaalee beacons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've restarted both of my devices and reinstalled the app, still running into the same problem and also its not firing `didEnterRegion:` and `didExitRegion:`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {

 [super viewDidLoad];    
//set peripheralManager delegate
self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                                 queue:nil
                                                               options:nil];


//Set location managaer delegate
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;


uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"E01D235B-A5DB-4717-8D2F-28D5B48931F1"];

// Setup a new region with that UUID and same identifier as the broadcasting beacon
self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"testRegion"];
self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Peripheral Manager Delegates

-(void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral
{
switch (peripheral.state) {
    case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn:
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
        break;
    case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff:
         statusLabel.text = @"Bluetooth is Off";
        [self clearFileds];
        [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
        break;
    case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnknown:
    default:
        statusLabel.text = @"Bluetooth is Unsupported";
        [self clearFileds];
        [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
        break;
   }

 }

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Location Manager Delecate Methods

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];

}

 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

switch (state) {
    case CLRegionStateInside:
        currentBeconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:currentBeconRegion];
        NSLog(@"INSIDE the Region");
        break;
    case CLRegionStateOutside:
        NSLog(@"OUTSIDE the Region");
        break;
    case CLRegionStateUnknown:
    default:
        NSLog(@"Region state UNKNOWN!!!");
        statusLabel.text = @"Region state UNKNOWN!!!";
       [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
        break;
    }
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
//check if we're ranging the correct beacon
if (![self.beaconRegion isEqual:region]) { return;}

NSLog(@"didEnterRegion");
if([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
{
    currentBeconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
    if ([beaconRegion.identifier isEqualToString:@"testRegion"])
    {

        //send local notificaation
        UILocalNotification *notice = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notice.alertBody = @"Becoan Found!!!";
        notice.alertAction =@"View";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notice];

        //srart raning beacon region
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:currentBeconRegion];


        }
    } 

 }
 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{

if ([beacons count] > 0) {

    int major = [beacons.firstObject major].intValue;
    int minor = [beacons.firstObject minor].intValue;

    if (major != self.foundBeacon.major.intValue || minor !=     self.foundBeacon.minor.intValue) {
        NSLog(@"Found Beacon is: %@", [beacons firstObject]);
    }

    self.foundBeacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
    self.foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];
    //Set the ui
    [self setFileds];

 }
else //[beacon count]  0
{
    statusLabel.text = @"No becaons found";
    [self clearsFileds];
   // [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
    }

}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
NSLog(@"didExitRegion");
if([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
{
    currentBeconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
    if ([beaconRegion.identifier isEqualToString:@"testRegion"])
    {
        [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:currentBeconRegion];

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that would explain your symptoms.  What kind of iBeacon are you using?  Can you try a different one to see if you get the same results?  If you have a second iOS device with BLE, you can use the free Locate for iBeacon app here:  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8  or if your mac has BLE, you can use the $9.99 MacBeacon here:  http://www.radiusnetworks.com/macbeacon-app.html

Comment: Strange! I've swapped the devices (iPad 3) as receiver  and (iPhone 4s) as sender, and is working as desired, don't no what is the fault and which device has it?

Comment: Strange indeed.  I would take whatever device has trouble receiving and try it with yet a different transmitter.  For what it is worth, I have used both iPhone 4s and iPad 3 devices in both roles successfully, so I doubt there is any issue related to those device types.

Comment: Why is this marked as solved when the problem still remains?

Comment: I have used your code and it help me alot. But in didRangeBeacons ,I got beacons count 0 and if I restart ibeacon device then it shows beacons count >0. I am not getting what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You say you are "inside the region" but how do you know the iBeacon is really being detected?  Is Bluetooth turned on and working?  Has the user allowed location access when prompted?

I would enable iBeacon ranging and log anything detected to verify your device really is seeing the iBeacon.  I suspect you will either find you do not detect anything, or perhaps the `iBeacon.proximity` field will be returning `CLProximityUnknown` due to a bad calibration.

The `didDetermineState` gets an extra call even if no beacons have ever been detected when you start up monitoring (or if you awake the screen when `notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES` is set on you region).  This is the only case where I would think you might get a `CLRegionStateUnknown` value.  I have never seen this value returned, so I am curious under what conditions it happens.  Finding the answers to my questions above may solve this.  Please report back!

Comment: That code looks OK to me.  It may sound silly, but I would reboot your phone and try again to make sure it is not in a bad state.  If you still have the problem, please also post your code where you set up the CLBeaconRegion and call `[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region]`

Answer (score 1):

This post was written based on iOS 8 this may change in the future:

I'm posting an answer here in case someone else is having the same problem as me.  I spent almost 4 hours on this in total before realizing that it was because my phone was in airplane mode.

**tl;dr**

If airplane mode is on, region notifications don't come through

Comment: After struggling with problem 1,5 days even i read your answer here but i still did not notice the problem were from airplane mode. iBeacon ranging perfectly working but monitoring not. It is shame that there is no error or whatsoever

Comment: @bpolat -- I did the same thing! I checked my code so many times before I found the problem.  I'm glad someone else found this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, and the answer was that I've simply forgotten to call:

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
```

I assumed wrongly at first that if you start ranging with:

```
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
```

... and getting data for rssi, accuracy and UUID in `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` method, the CLLocationManager  should be able to figure out that the phone was in that region, but apparently not. So when asking for state, with:

```
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:beaconRegion];
```

I got `CLRegionStateUnknown` for that region in the `locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:` like you did.